# Unsure about a spoken word

Tags: phrase-requests

https://www.dropbox.com/s/506txfpwodov9fp/untitled.wma?dl=0

Can a native speaker help me with this soundbyte?
I think the word I'm looking for is 'wanted' but all I hear is 'wonted'.

The accent sounds a bit weird to me, I want to make sure I'm hearing the right word.

The best and most [?]... thing we should respect the most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I thought he had some British-German accent and was saying "wanted" with the w more like a v, but after a few more listenings I think he's just British and is saying "most vaunted", meaning the most praised or hyped.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/vaunted

Comment: Thanks. Here's a bit more of the context: https://youtu.be/V4xnDC55vPw?t=57s Can you confirm it's vaunted? I think the accent is Scottish.

Comment: I cannot think of anything else that it could be. It's a somewhat odd word choice -- "vaunted" usually has a slight negative connotation, and is usually like a group/media consensus on something rather than one person saying something is important or good. But it works well enough, and it makes more sense than "wanted" which is the only other contender.